# MongoServerError: $_internalSearchMongotRemote is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas, fuzzy-search

```
let searchResult = await UserModel.aggregate([
        {
            $search: {
                index: indexes.USERS_SEARCH_INDEX,
                text: {
                    query: searchText,
                    path: [
                        'profile.first_name',
                        'profile.last_name',
                        'profile.current_organization',
                        'profile.current_position',
                        'profile.headline',
                    ],
                    fuzzy: {
                        maxEdits: 2,
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Trying to implement fuzzy searching using Atlas Search reference -
https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/search

Running this code returns the following error -

```
MongoServerError: $_internalSearchMongotRemote is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline
```

Comment: I was using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-delete, which was breaking the aggregation. Fixed it by removing the package.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it - add that info as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

I was using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-delete, which was breaking the aggregation. Fixed it by removing the package. Thanks!